# System Requirements for running a SignalR chat application

Tags: system, signalr, requirements

I am writing a report at university to go along side my final project software, a SignalR chat application.

In the methodology I am a bit stuck on the system requirements. I know that there are certain system requirements for building a signalR application because I had to meet them myself, but what are the system requirements of running one?

I have written about O/S and browsers, but what else is a requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any good answer over internet?

Answer (score 0):

Signalr Server Requirements are basically Windows 7 or higher

and client side browser of I.E 8+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari

See [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms) for exact specifications